# Guidelines for PDF Conversion

Tags: marklogic, pdf-conversion

I am using MarkLogic to generate XML files for PDF documents which has images, formatted text (italic and bold), tables etc. Can you please provide some guidelines for the best conversion. I am using normal conversion with following pipelines:

- Conversion Processing
- DocBook Conversion
- HTML Conversion
- PDF Conversion
- PDF Conversion (Page Layout, Image Batching)
- Status Change Handling

The images are not maintained with their title and format also not maintained. Tables are appearing as normal paragraph in the generated XML.

Answer (score 2):

Part of document conversion is building **CSS** files to handle the formatting, as well as grabbing the images in the document. Both go into the database. When you use a browser to view the document, make sure that the links to the images and **CSS** work. You may need to change them from, say, `/doc1.css` to something like `/get.xqy?uri=doc1.css`. Also, it's possible that other **CSS** on the page is interfering with the document's **CSS**.

Comment: I agree with Dave - if you look in Firebug or another browser debugger, you'll probably see requests for css (and/or images) failing.

Comment: I want to introduce some tag (say <italic>) around the text in italics. Also, more concerned about tables provided the tables do not have borders but values are separated using tabs.